# Transform the Excel data into system-friendly data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As AI cannot solve this we need humans to solve this. So I have been given stupidly formatted data and I need to convert it into system friendly data so I can automate reading and save huge amount of time and minimize the errors.

So I have data following:

| Blank | Client1 | Client2 | Client3 | Client4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ProductId1 | ProductAmount | ProductAmount | ProductAmount | ProductAmount |
| ProductId2 | ProductAmount | ProductAmount | ProductAmount | ProductAmount |
| ProductId3 | ProductAmount | ProductAmount | ProductAmount | ProductAmount |
| ProductId3 | ProductAmount | ProductAmount | ProductAmount | ProductAmount |

I would like to have the data following format:

| ClientID | ProductId | ProductAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client1 | ProductId1 | ProductAmount |
| Client1 | ProductId2 | ProductAmount |
| Client1 | ProductId3 | ProductAmount |
| Client1 | ProductId4 | ProductAmount |
| Client2 | ProductId2 | ProductAmount |
| Client2 | ProductId3 | ProductAmount |
| Client3 | ProductId1 | ProductAmount |
| Client3 | ProductId2 | ProductAmount |
| Client4 | ProductId1 | ProductAmount |
| Client4 | ProductId2 | ProductAmount |
| Client4 | ProductId3 | ProductAmount |
| Client4 | ProductId4 | ProductAmount |

So every Row have to have ClientID and IF product amount >0 then add it's productId and the amount. I think you got the point.

Trying different formulas and lost my total hope for ChatGPT as well... I would like to make sustainable solution which I can use like monthly. Solution should be created using Excel at the moment so I would like to have the formulas (maybe macro).

Comment: Power Query -> Unpivot Columns

Comment: Or, in `MS365` --> `=SORT(HSTACK(TOCOL(IFNA(B1:E1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:E5)))),TOCOL(IFNA(A2:A5,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(B2:E5)))),TOCOL(B2:E5)),1)`